# Any other way to dynamically add new rows and submit the contents to the database other than gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am currently using the code below dynamically add new rows to Gridview and submit successfully subbmit the contents to the database.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("[id$=txtdate]").datepicker({

                showOn: 'button',

                buttonImageOnly: true,

                buttonImage: 'images/20/calendar200.gif'

            });

        });

    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
     $(window).load(function () {
         //Attach click event to button
         $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
             //Get Values from dropdownlist
             var sHour = $('#startHour').val();
             var sMinutes = $('#startMinutes').val();
             var sAmPm = $('#startAmPm').val();

             var eHour = $('#endHour').val();
             var eMinutes = $('#endMinutes').val();
             var eAmPm = $('#endAmPm').val();

             //create date format from dropdownlist selected values 
             var theDate = $('#txtdate').val()
             var timeStart = new Date(theDate + ' ' + sHour + ':' + sMinutes + ' ' + sAmPm).getHours();
             var timeEnd = new Date(theDate + ' ' + eHour + ':' + eMinutes + ' ' + eAmPm).getHours();

             //Calulate the time difference
             var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;

             //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
             if (hourDiff < 4) {
                 alert("A mininum of 4 hours is required!");
             }
         });
     });//]]>  

</script>

Then markup
        <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event Date(s)">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server" class = "Calender"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdate"
                                ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:DropDownList id="startHour" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="startHour"
                                ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minutes">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:DropDownList id="startMinutes" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="startMinutes"
                                ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AM/PM">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:DropDownList id="startAmPm" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="startAmPm"
                                ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>&nbsp;
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Time">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:DropDownList id="endHour" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="endHour"
                                ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Minutes">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:DropDownList id="endMinutes" runat="server" CSClass="fptextbox12">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="startMinutes"
                                ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="Select"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AM/PM">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:DropDownList id="endAmPm" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="endAmPm"
                                ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Another Event" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#AC54AA" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#AC54AA" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
             </asp:gridview>
            <br />
         </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Send Request" OnClick="btnSave_Click" alt="Send Request" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" style ="font-weight:bold; font-size:large" runat="server"></asp:Label>

 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Send Reservation Request" OnClick="btnSave_Click" alt="Send Request" /><br />
```

This works fine in terms of adding new rows to gridview and submit the entire data to the database.

The problem I have is that my validation is no longer working.

For instance, we have a requirement that a user making some reservations must choose a minimum of 4 hours.

If a user chooses less than 4 hours between start time and end time, this alert below is raised:

**A mininum of 4 hours is required!**

This worked very well (Thanks in larget part to the great help I received here) until I switched to Gridview.

No errors exist, however, the alert is no longer working.

Is there another way of dynamically adding rows in an asp.net form (not gridview) and still be able to successfully submit to the database?

Or better yet, any ideas what I need to change to the way JQuery is handling gridview controls to allow the validations to work?

I have spent literally all day trying to figure this out to no avail.

Comment: Are you trying to do your validation on data change event, after data change, before data change?

Comment: @Matches, I am doing my validation on button click. So, obviously on event change.

Comment: button click != event change for a data grid. I'm asking what your intent is when doing validation, not what you're doing right now. For example, if you check is changing you can prevent bad data from going in to the grid - or is changed to revert the changes and log an issue.

Comment: @Matches, I am hoping that I am understanding your question. What we would like to do is prevent a user from submitting a request to reserve a space if the user attempts to make reservation or less than 4 hours. For instance, if you wish to reserve a space on one of the camps for 07/12/2014, and you select a start time of 5:00PM and an end time of 8:00PM, that's less than 4 hours. The system should alert you that you have to make a minimum of 4 hours and then stop you from going any further until you selet at least 4 hours. The code works but not in gridview. Hope this is clear now.